# How to export to csv info from associated models?

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

For example I have model Order and associated models Shipping and Cart.
How to export info from each shipping and cart using for example @order.to_csv to one file?

Comment: For example I have variable order. And I need to export order.organization.name and order.contact_information.address to csv into the one file. How can I do this?

Comment: I see your question, i ask about your attempt.

Comment: I don't really know how to implement this.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't code-writing resource, show what you did so far and what is not working, so we can try to help you..

Comment: This might help you get started http://bit.ly/1xSgVEW
By the way, I do agree with @Зелёный, you should try out something before asking. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking out the RailsCasts tutorial on exporting CSV and Excel. http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

You should also review Ruby's documentation on its built-in CSV functionality. 
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Just starting out with stackoverflow. Just trying to be helpful. The question didn't provide any code and it seemed like he was just starting to tackle the problem. I figured both links were a good place to start.